# handlebars dynamic partial names

Tags: dynamic, handlebars.js, partials

i have a component in my example an accordion and i want to reuse it with different templates inside it's content-area.

what i have achieved is to create the accordion.

```
<div class="c_accordion">
    {{#each data}}
    <div class="c_accordion__item">
        <h3 class="c_accordion__headline">{{this.title}}</h3>
        <div class="c_accordion__content">
            {{../template}} <-- renders [object object]
            {{> ('../template') data=this.content}}  <-- there i want to render diffrent templates
            {{> list data=this.content}}  <-- this works without problems
        </div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
</div>
```

And now i want to render different templates insinde my accordion (for example a list partial)

```
{{> accordion template=list data=about.services}}
```

But i always get an error "Warning: The partial undefined could not be found Use"

I tried it also with the helper lookup, but also the same result with an error.

Generally is that the correct way or there are others approaches to solve this problem??

I'm using grunt-assemble to build static sites. this is the handlbars version ## v4.0.5 - November 19th, 2015

gregor

Answer (score -1):

ok i found a solution ;)

based on this
[assemble - Render a list of strings as Handlebars partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403594/assemble-render-a-list-of-strings-as-handlebars-partial)

```
//insert the accordion
{{> accordion partial="list" data=about.services}}

//accordion.hbs
<div class="c_accordion">
     ...
     {{dynamicPartial ../partial this.content}}
     ...
</div>

//helper dynamicPartial
module.exports.register = function (Handlebars, context)  { 
    Handlebars.registerHelper('dynamicPartial', function(name, data) {
        var partial = Handlebars.partials[name];
        var template = Handlebars.compile(partial);
        var output = template({"data": data});
        return new Handlebars.SafeString(output);
    })
};

//list.hbs
<ul>
    {{#each data}}
    <li>{{this}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```